# Why are the headings in my navigation menu not going into the hamburger menu when it is zoomed in by 250%?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have been trying to fix my hamburger menu so that the headings go into it, in the navigation bar. However, it is not working. Does anyone know of a fix to this? I am new to programming so the code might be messy.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <head>
      <title>My Website</title>
      <meta charset="UTF-8">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
   </head>
   <body>
      <header>
         <nav>
            <ul>
               <li><a href="home.html">Home</a></li>
               <li><a href="#">Products</a></li>
               <li><a href="#">Services</a></li>
               <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
               <li><a href="#">Team</a></li>
               <li><a href="#">Blog</a></li>
               <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
               <div class="logo" onclick="location.href='navigationbar.html'"></div>
               <div class="hamburger" id="hamburger">
                  <span class="bar"></span>
                  <span class="bar"></span>
                  <span class="bar"></span>
               </div>
            </ul>
         </nav>
      </header>
      <script>
         const hamburger = document.querySelector(".hamburger");
         const navList = document.querySelector("ul");
         
         hamburger.addEventListener("click", () => {
           hamburger.classList.toggle("open");
           navList.classList.toggle("active");
         });
      </script>
      <style>
         @import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Hind+Madurai:wght@300&display=swap');
         nav {
         display: flex;
         justify-content: center;
         align-items: center;
         }      
         nav div.logo {
         margin-right: -80px; 
         order: -1;
         }
         nav ul {
         list-style: none;
         margin: 0;
         padding: 0;
         display: flex;
         justify-content: center;
         align-items: center; 
         text-align: center;
         }
         body {
         font-family: 'Hind Madurai', sans-serif;
         margin: 0;
         }
         header {
         background-color: #333;
         color: #fff;
         }
         nav ul {
         list-style: none;
         margin: 0;
         padding: 0;
         display: flex;
         justify-content: center;
         align-items: center; 
         height: 55px; 
         }
         nav li {
         margin-right: 5px;
         padding: 10px;
         }
         nav li:first-child {
         margin-left: 100px;
         }
         nav ul li a {
         text-decoration: none;
         }
         nav ul li a:hover {
         border-bottom: none;
         color: #D1D1D1;
         }
         nav a {
         color: #fff;
         text-decoration: none;
         font-weight: bold;
         }
         nav a:hover {
         color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
         }
         .logo {
         width: 30px;
         height: 30px;
         background-image: url('clarekicon3.svg');
         background-size: contain;
         background-repeat: no-repeat;
         background-position: center;
         transition: background-color 1s ease; 
         max-width: 100px; 
         }
         .logo:hover {
         background-image: url('clarekicon3hover.svg');
         }
         @media only screen and (min-width: 900px) {
         .logo {
         background-image: url('clarkelogo2.svg');
         width: 80px;
         height: 80px;
         transition: background-color 0.5s ease
         }
         }
         @media only screen and (min-width: 900px) {
         .logo:hover {
         background-image: url('clarkelogo2hover.svg');
         }}
         ul {
         margin: 0;
         padding: 0;
         }
         li {
         margin-bottom: -5px;
         }
         .button:hover {
         background-color: #ccc;
         color: #333;
         }
         footer {
         position: fixed;
         bottom: 0;
         width: 100%;
         background-color: #333;
         color: #fff;
         padding: 0px;
         }
         .grey-hover:hover {
         background-color: #ccc;
         color: #333;
         }
         .hamburger-menu {
         font-size: 20px;
         cursor: pointer;
         }
         nav ul.active {
         display: flex;
         flex-direction: column;
         position: absolute;
         top: 55px;
         left: 0;
         width: 100%;
         background-color: #333;
         z-index: 1;
         }
         nav ul.active li {
         margin-right: 0;
         padding: 10px;
         }
         nav ul.active li:first-child {
         margin-left: 0;
         }
         @media (max-width: 900px) {
         .hamburger {
         display: block;
         position: absolute;
         right: 20px;
         top: 15px;
         width: 30px;
         height: 30px;
         cursor: pointer;
         z-index: 2;
         }
         .bar {
         display: block;
         width: 25px;
         height: 3px;
         margin: 5px auto;
         background-color: #fff;
         transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
         }
         .hamburger.open .bar:nth-child(1) {
         transform: translateY(8px) rotate(45deg);
         }
         .hamburger.open .bar:nth-child(2) {
         opacity: 0;
         }
         .hamburger.open .bar:nth-child(3) {
         transform: translateY(-8px) rotate(-45deg);
         }
         .nav-list {
         display: none;
         position: absolute;
         top: 55px;
         left: 0;
         width: 100%;
         background-color: #333;
         z-index: 1;
         }
         .nav-list li {
         margin-right: 0;
         padding: 10px;
         }
         .nav-list li:first-child {
         margin-left: 0;
         }
         .nav-list a {
         display: block;
         color: #fff;
         font-size: 18px;
         padding: 10px;
         text-align: center;
         text-decoration: none;
         }
         .nav-list a:hover {
         background-color: #444;
         }
         .nav-list.active {
         display: flex;
         flex-direction: column;
         }
         }
      </style>
   </body>
</html>
```

I tried using ChatGPT to see if it could fix the problem. However, it did not. I also asked some people on discord and no one was able to give a clear answer.

Answer (score 0):

Usually the implementation of a responsive site navigation consists of a button that shows or hides the menu on mobile screens. The same button is not visible on desktop and the menu would be visible on desktop by default.

The problem with your implementation is that you do not have any JS logic that would be moving it in the hamburger div, so that cannot be expected in any way.

W3Schools has a nice beginner tutorial which you can read, which achieves a responsive navigation menu (full tutorial on https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_topnav_responsive.asp ):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<style>
body {
  margin: 0;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

.topnav {
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #333;
}

.topnav a {
  float: left;
  display: block;
  color: #f2f2f2;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 17px;
}

.topnav a:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
  color: black;
}

.topnav a.active {
  background-color: #04AA6D;
  color: white;
}

.topnav .icon {
  display: none;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .topnav a:not(:first-child) {display: none;}
  .topnav a.icon {
    float: right;
    display: block;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .topnav.responsive {position: relative;}
  .topnav.responsive .icon {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
  }
  .topnav.responsive a {
    float: none;
    display: block;
    text-align: left;
  }
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<div class="topnav" id="myTopnav">
  <a href="#home" class="active">Home</a>
  <a href="#news">News</a>
  <a href="#contact">Contact</a>
  <a href="#about">About</a>
  <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="icon" onclick="myFunction()">
    <i class="fa fa-bars"></i>
  </a>
</div>

<div style="padding-left:16px">
  <h2>Responsive Topnav Example</h2>
  <p>Resize the browser window to see how it works.</p>
</div>

<script>
function myFunction() {
  var x = document.getElementById("myTopnav");
  if (x.className === "topnav") {
    x.className += " responsive";
  } else {
    x.className = "topnav";
  }
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```